# Spring Boot 2.1/2.2 testing - how to test a single controller without creating beans for everything else?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, kotlin

Before in Spring Boot 2.0 I had something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
@SpringBootTest
@WithUserDetails
class MyControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var myController: MyController

    lateinit var mvc: MockMvc

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build()
    }
...
```

But after trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1, I get various random errors, such as:

1. WithUserDetails not working: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(value=user, userDetailsServiceBeanName=, setupBefore=TEST_METHOD)`
2. Irrelevant beans were (attempting) to be created: `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property <property> has not been initialized` - this was from a `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

and a few more other stuff that just didn't make sense to me (in 2.2, I can't have both `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest` together either).

Does anyone have an idea for what I would need to do to correctly update these unit tests?

Comment: Why do you use DataJpaTest to test an MVC controller. DataJpaTest is for testing Spring Data JPA repositories. How to test controllers in isolation is documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests

Comment: I'm not sure - it's just what was already there when I started working on the code base. Thanks, I'll look into using `@WebMvcTest`!

Answer (score 0):

You use either a sliced test `@WebMvcTest` or a full integration test with `@SpringBootTest`. Hence it has no sense in using them together. In your case you want to test a controller, then use the `@WebMvcTest` and mock the dependencies.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@WithUserDetails
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var myController: MyController

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mvc: MockMvc


    @MockBean
    var myService: MyServiceForController
```

Use `@MockBean` to mock the service dependencies for the controller and register behavior on it. You can now also simply wire the controller and a pre-setup `MockMvc` instance instead of wiring that yourself.